# How can I reduce to time when I read the data and how can I deal with the memory error?

Tags: python, pandas

The error I am gettin is this "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory".  The data I am reading in is 5,201,073 KB and furthermore, I need to merge it with two-three small datasets.

The code I use to read the data is this:
`pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/WorldValueSurvey/outcome/outcome_220723.csv", low_memory=False)`

Probably my data is so big when I read the data using `pd.read_csv` it takes so much time and sometimes gives the memory error. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but have you tried setting `low_memory=True`?  It should be more economical with memory that way.

Comment: I thought exactly the same, but once it said you should set low_memory=False. Let me try as you said. Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.